# Splitting a dataframe into chunks based on multiple conditions for a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, split

I have a large dataframe (+200 million rows) that is in the following format

```
DeviceID    Date_Time
50135487    2018-03-01 00:00:44
50135487    2018-03-02 01:01:21
50135487    2018-03-01 02:01:58
50135484    2018-03-01 02:01:58
50135484    2018-03-01 02:50:13
50090879    2018-03-01 02:50:13
50090879    2018-03-01 02:50:13
50090860    2018-03-01 02:50:13
50090860    2018-03-01 02:50:13
```

Since the data frame has about 7700 unique 'DeviceID' values, I want to split the large data frame into 8 smaller dataframes so that I can run the analysis on them quicker.

I've tried using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
np.array_split(df, 3)
```

but it produced dataframes where the a specific `DeviceID` is found in multiple dataframes.

I'm imagining that the solution would include an `if` statement combined with `groupby`, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Why do you assume that splitting it would allow you to run your analysis faster? I can only imagine that this case is true if you're using multiprocessing where each CPU core is performing the analysis in parallel

Comment: use more_itertools.... check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770013/pandas-split-dataframe-into-multiple-when-condition-is-true

Comment: i though of splitting it because i'm having trouble converting the timestamp using `pd.to_datetime` command and then split the formatted date and time into two different columns with this format: `%d/%m/%Y` and `%H:%M:%S` It is taking a lot of time to make that conversion.

Comment: @RenaldoMoon - Anyway you need to go through the entire data frame so it shouldn't make any difference (I might be wrong, I just don't get how it would result in faster computations). However, I have ran into this project called [modin](https://github.com/modin-project/modin) that reads data frames using multiple core rather than only one (the case with pandas) and it really is fast. Take a look at it, it might help you achieve your goal

Comment: @RenaldoMoon I suggest you to skip `pd.to_datetime` and use `df["Date_Time"].astype("M8")` instead.

Comment: Then you can have a look at  [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) or [vaex](https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for out of core dataframe. These tools are going to manage the splitting for you so you can just run a  groupby.

Answer (score 1):

To split your DataFrame into a number of "bins", keeping each *DeviceID* in
a single bin, take the following approach:

- Compute *value_counts* for *DeviceID*. The result is a *Series*
  starting with most numerous groups.
- Convert it to a *DataFrame* and add a column composed of bin numbers,
  cycling from *0* to *binNo*.

The code to do it is:

```
binNo = 3    # Number of bins
vc = df.DeviceID.value_counts().rename('cnt')
vc = vc.to_frame().assign(bin=[ i % binNo for i in range(vc.size) ]); vc
```

For my example data (slightly changed and expanded your sample), the result is:

```
          cnt  bin
50135487    2    0
50135484    2    1
50090860    2    2
50090879    2    0
50090869    1    1
50090850    1    2
50135488    1    0
```

*cnt* is the number of occurrences of each *DeviceID* and *bin* is the bin
assignment for this *DeviceID*.

Then define a function generating list of *DeviceID*s for bin *n*:

```
def genDf(n):
    return vc[vc.bin == n].index
```

And to generate the list of DataFrames (bins), execute:

```
dfLst = [ df[df.DeviceID.isin(genDf(i))] for i in range(binNo) ]
```